# SPSS Calculate percentiles with weighted average

Tags: spss

My background is in databases and SQL coding.  I’ve used the CTABLES feature in SPSS a little, mostly for calculating percentiles which is slow in sql.  But now I have a data set where I need to calculate percentiles for a weighted average which is not as straightforward, and I can’t figure out if it’s possible in SPSS or not.

I have data similar to the following

```
Country Region  District       Units    Cost per Unit
USA       Central   DivisionQ   10       3
USA       Central   DivisionQ   12      2.5
USA       Central   DivisionQ   25      1.5
USA       Central   DivisionQ   6       4
USA       Central   DivisionA   3       3.25
USA       Central   DivisionA   76      1.75
USA       Central   DivisionA   42      1.5
USA       Central   DivisionA   1       8
USA       Eastern   DivisionQ   14      3
USA       Eastern   DivisionQ   25      2.5
USA       Eastern   DivisionQ   75      1.5
USA       Eastern   DivisionQ   9       4
USA       Eastern   DivisionA   100     3.25
USA       Eastern   DivisionA   4       1.75
USA       Eastern   DivisionA   33      1.5
USA       Eastern   DivisionA   17      8
                               452     51
```

For every possible segmentation (Country, Country-Region, Country-Region-District, Country-District etc.)
I want to get the Avg. Cost per Unit, ie.  Cost per Unit weighted by Units, so that is total SUM(Units*CostPerUnit)/SUM(Units)

And  I  need to get the 10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th percentiles for each possible segmentation.

The way I do this part in SQL is extract all the rows in the segment, sort and rank by Cost Per Unit.  Get a running sum of Units for each row.  Determine the ratio of that running sum to the total units, and that percentage determines which row has the Cost Per Unit for that percentile.  An example , for Country = USA and Division = Q

```
                                                       Unit Running
Country                  Units  Cost        Unit        divided by
                               Per Unit    Running     Total Units
USA   Central  DivisionQ    25  1.5          25         0.14    10th 
USA   Eastern  DivisionQ    75  1.5         100         0.56    25th/50 
USA   Central  DivisionQ    12  2.5         112         0.63
USA   Eastern  DivisionQ    25  2.5         137         0.77    75th 
USA   Central  DivisionQ    10  3           147         0.83
USA   Eastern  DivisionQ    14  3           161         0.91    90th 
USA   Central  DivisionQ    6   4           167         0.94
USA   Eastern  DivisionQ    9   4           176         1
```

This takes a very long time to do for each segment.  Is it possible to leverage SPSS to do the same thing more easily?

Answer (score 1):

Use SPLIT FILES (Data > Select Cases) to define the group and then use FREQUENCIES (Analyze > Descriptive Statistics > Frequencies) to calculate the statistics. Suppress the actual frequency tables (/FORMAT=NOTABLE).